# Chrome extension Requirements - only for Windows users

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, chrome-native-messaging

I have a extension, which using "Native Messaging API" to communicate with Windows program. So it means, that this extension is useless on devices like Mac or Chromebook. Is there any option, how can I show my extension in store only for devices with Windows ?
I have in description, that it only works on Windows, but people are lazy and instead of reading, they give me bad ratings.

Comment: Maybe you can add `for Windows` in its name, IANAL but maybe it's okay to include MS trademark product name in such fashion.

Comment: and a bit of code that checks your os using navigator.platform and alerts the user if they cant use it.

Comment: and code in your extension that *gracely* handles the non windows case and shows a nice explanation to the user.

Comment: And use chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function(info) { info.os == "win" }) instead of navigator.platform.

Comment: thanks for tips
But it means, there is no way how to hide my extension in chrome store for other platforms, right ?